# Check if file is present doesn't work in Android. Always says that the file isn't present

Tags: java, android, file

I have a function to check if a ZIP file is present (/storage/emulated/0/Music/ron.zip). If not it should get downloaded. It always gives me false, so it downloads every time (ron-1.zip...). I tried several variations and nothing works, always false.
Thanks for your help.

```
MainActivity.java

public boolean isFilePresent() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/ron.zip";
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.isFile();
}

if(!isFilePresent()){
    Downloader dl = new Downloader(this);
    dl.execute("http://somewebpage/ron.zip");
}

manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Check if its really in your external storage or internal. Check this link to read more about storage in Android. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **file.exists()** function to check file is exist or not instead of **file.isFile()**.

*public boolean isFile() ->* Test whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a normal file. A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory-file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.